# Compare column by column

Tags: c++, opencv

In this method I would like to find die biggest distance between two (adjecent) points for *each* column in a `cv::Mat`. In the end the corresponding points (which have the biggest distance to each other) should be returned.

To achive this, I already researched a lot and now I stuck at this code snippet:

```
cv::Mat mat;
std::vector<cv::Point> pointVec, finalPointVec;
std::vector<float> allDist;
for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {
        c = mat.col(j);

        if (c.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] == 0
            && c.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] == 0
            && c.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] == 255) {
            cv::Point diPoint(j, i);

            pointVec.push_back(diPoint);

            if (pointVec[j].x == pointVec[j + 1].x) {
                //std::cout << pointVec[j].y << "\n";

                float diffY = pointVec[j].y - pointVec[j + 1].y;
                float diffX = pointVec[j].x - pointVec[j + 1].x;
                float dist = sqrt((diffY * diffY) + (diffX * diffX));
                for (int d = 0; d < pointVec[j].x; d++) {

                    allDist.push_back(dist);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So I already iterate through the `cv::Mat` and also calculate the distance. Now I would like to implement finding the biggest distance for *each* column. Here I'm asking for your help, how I could realize it. Although I thought `if (pointVec[j].x == pointVec[j + 1].x)` should be fine to find the same columns, but it seems to be the wrong implementation. Also - how may I return those points, which have the largest distance to each other?

Maybe for some me clarification, here an image, how it should look like (the circled points should be those, which has to be returned):
[image]

I'm happy about any answer!

Comment: First, loop over columns. For clarity, I recommend calling a function like "find_greatest_distance" inside that loop. That function should loop over rows in the column, with an algorithm along the lines of "foreach first point, foreach second point calculate distance and remember it if it's greater than the current remembered distance".

Comment: @PaulHicks I'm actually already loop over columns and rows? Or what do you mean?

Comment: You're currently looping over rows first, then columns. You need to do it the other way around. Plus you need an extra loop: you need to nest a column loop inside a column loop. I recommend using functions, it will be too messy and hard to follow if you do it all in one block of code.

Comment: What do you mean that the distance should be compared only between points in the same column? `col[j]` and `col[j+1]` are different columns.

Comment: You have to rewrite the condition since now it's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to calculate distances between all points in each column, or only between the pairs of points that are adjacent to each other in a particular column?

Comment: @KjMag after some further approach, I edited my code and question, hopefully it's more understandable now.

Comment: Do all points within a single column have the same `x` value? Can you provide the example input matrix for the picture?

Comment: Do you need to keep all the distances at allDist vector, or do you use it only as a temporary variable for searching for the biggest distance later?

Comment: @KjMag I keep it for the biggest distance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the task correctly, you need to divide your algorithm into two phases as I think you can't do these two things efficiently within the same loops:

1. Populating `pointVec`
2. Iterating through `pointVec` and calculating distances

### **Populating `pointVec`**

```
cv::Mat mat;
std::vector<cv::Point> pointVec;
const cv::Vec3b sought_value(0, 0, 255);

for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {

        if (mat.at<Vec3b>(i, j) == sought_value) {
            pointVec.emplace_back(cv::Point(i, j));
        }

    }
}
```

I used `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()` and eliminated the temporary variable for storing the point, even though in this case the performance difference might be little due to optimizations. I've also introduced `sought_value` because I think it's easier to read that way, but it's up to you which version you choose.

### Iterating through `pointVec` and calculating distances

Step 2 is going to be much easier if we sort `pointVec` with respect to columns, and then to rows, beforehand. That way we know that consecutive points are usually adjacent to each other and belong to the same column. Also, I'm going to use `std::tuple<int, float, std::pair<cv::Point, cv::Point>>` for storing the max distance of each column together with column number and points to which the distance refers since that way we can easily locate the points and search maximum distance for each column as you wanted.

```
// keeps the results - column number, distance and points respectively:
using ColDistPointsTuple = std::tuple<int, float, std::pair<cv::Point, cv::Point>>;
std::vector <ColDistPointsTuple> column_maxes;

std::sort(column_maxes.begin(), column_maxes.end(),
    [](const cv::Point& a, const cv::Point& b) -> bool
    {
    if (a.x < b.x)
        return true;
    else if (a.x == b.x)
        return a.y < b.y;
    else
        return false;
    }
);

for (int j = 0; j < pointVec.size() - 1; ++j) // note '-1' here - otherwise you'll get out of bounds exception 
{
    if (pointVec[j].x == pointVec[j + 1].x) {

        float diffY = pointVec[j].y - pointVec[j + 1].y;
        float diffX = pointVec[j].x - pointVec[j + 1].x;
        float dist = sqrt((diffY * diffY) + (diffX * diffX));

        if (!column_maxes.empty())
        {
            if (std::get<0>(column_maxes.back()) == pointVec[j].x) // belongs to the same column
            {
                if (dist > std::get<1>(column_maxes.back())) // distance greater than the one stored for that column
                {
                    column_maxes.back() = 
                        std::make_tuple( pointVec[j].x, dist, pointVec[j], pointVec[j + 1] );
                    continue;
                }
            } 
        }

        column_maxes.emplace_back( pointVec[j].x, dist, pointVec[j], pointVec[j+1] );

    }
}
```

`column_maxes` holds column number, dist, and points respectively. I could have skipped the column number, but I think searching for elements based e.g. on the first coordinate of a point belonging to a pair belonging to a tuple (ugh!) in a vector would be really ugly and counterintuitive. The tuple above is not the prettiest thing in terms of syntax, but I think matches the way you want to use the results.

I had no chance to test this solution so it might contain some minor errors, but the general idea should work.

If you are going to do a lot of searching based on the column number, consider using `std::map` with the column number as a key, and a tuple consisting of distance and a pair of `cv::Point`s as values. The basic algorithm would look the same, but you'd have to replace calls to `operator[]` with map iterators then. Also points insertion would be slower, so this solution has its pros and cons just like the one shown above.